# Java executing rSync shell command with progress display

Tags: java, shell, unix, child-process

I basically want to write a simple GUI program to sync to directories using the `rsync` command. The core part of the code is below. My main question is, do I need to have the `waitFor` method included? At present, I have left it out, because I would like to show the user the `--progress` responses as it would in terminal, not wait until the end. Is this a bad idea?

```
public void executeCommand(String src, String dest) {
        System.out.println("Starting shell");
    Process p;
    try {
                System.out.println("Creating process...");
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rsync --progress -va "+src +" "+ dest );
        //p.waitFor(); <- is this important?
                    System.out.println("Creating reader...");
        BufferedReader reader =
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));                       
                    String line = "";
                    System.out.println("Starting sync...");
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {             
                            System.out.println(line);                              
                            textAreaAppend(line);   
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

   public void textAreaAppend(String line){
    textArea.append(line +"\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process.waitFor will terminate the current thread until the process is terminated. Thus, at the place where you commented it out, it does not make any sense at all. You might consider putting a p.waitFor() *after* the loop, as to continue with your program only when the process has terminated.

Apart from that, sorry to say so, your code is a mess. You use a very outdated method to start the process, you do not read stderr (which may lead to blocking conditions on stdout), code format is all over the place, p is declared outside the try block without any reason, exception handling is not present.

To at least cover the basic necessities of reading both stdin and stderr, you should go for process builder and redirect stderr to stdout:

```
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList("rsync", "--progress", "-va", src, dest));
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    builder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE);
    Process p = builder.start();
```

Comment: Thanks @mtj, I really appreciate your constructive criticism. Do I understand correctly that with these redirects, the errorstream will be included in my `reader`?

Comment: Yes. The redirectErrorStream(true) call will stream the error to the same channel as stdout (so you only have to read one stream, not two) and the redirectOutput(PIPE) will supply this as a stream as used in p.getInputStream().